# Weird javascript code convention with "const"

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

What is this code convention in javascript?

**const { navigate } = //whatever**

As in, what sense does it make. I saw it in RNs React navigation

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's named destructuring. When you have an object and you want to take only a property of that object, you can get only it by using that convention.

```
let fullName = { 
  first: 'John',
  last: 'Smith'
}

const { first } = fullName;
```

You can take a look here for more info's

http://wesbos.com/destructuring-renaming/

Answer (score 0):

It's called destructuring

Example:

```
var myObject = {a: "what", b: "ever"};
const {a} = myObject;
console.log(a);       // will give "what"
```